# Refreshing a Image on page using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to reload the image automatically , after searching a lot i found a way..but i can not figure out how to refresh it. This is what i have tried:

```
'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {

  if (response == true) {

    var dataa = data.replace('~/NightlifeClientuploads/Events/', '');
    var Datanew = dataa.split('.')[0];                         
    d = new Date();

    $('#'+Datanew).attr('src', '/NightlifeSite/NightlifeClientuploads/Events/'+ dataa+'?' + d.getTime());
  }
```

I am getting my variables as:

```
    dataa = '142727480524.jpg'
    Datanew = '142727480524'
```

and this image is located in the path i have given!

Still it is not getting reloaded

**Update:** 
 check my explorer screenshot 
[image]

Comment: Above to work you need a `img` with `id="142727480524"` in `DOM`

Comment: ya there is a img With that id in DOM,,but that is displaying as broken image..if i right click on that broken image and reload it ,then image displaying finely!!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove initial `/` and try as below:

```
$('#'+Datanew).attr('src', 'NightlifeSite/NightlifeClientuploads/Events/'+ dataa+'?' + d.getTime());
```